# Mongoose promises not resolving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get data from a mongo db and then send it as an sms.
Here is my code:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import mediaModel from '../MediaSchema'
import requestPromise from 'request-promise'
var request = require('request');

export default (app) => {
app.get( '/sms/:number', (req, res) => {
    var number = req.params.number;
    return req.mediaModel
        .find({'time': number})
        .exec()
        .then(function(data) {
        return request({
            url: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<MyId>/Messages', 
            method: 'POST',
            auth: {
                user: '<MyID>',
                pass: '<MyToken>'
            },
            form: {
                From: '123456789',
                To: '987654321',
                Body: data.url
            }
        })  
    });
    })
}
```

The call to my sms service returns a socket hangup. If I change the form to say 
`form: {
    From: '123456789',
    To: '987654321',
    Body: "data.url"
 }`

It works because I am not trying to resolve "data"
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly not resolving the `request`, which should actually be returning a promise? Looks that way from here. So you would need another `.then()` and then actually use `res.send()` or `res.json()`, otherwise the url request is just going to hang there.

Comment: @NeilLunn You were correct. Thank you! Unfortunately I can't give you the answer since you just commented. If you want the credit please submit an answer. Additionally it was failing because when I would pass the data into the form it didn't know how to parse it. A friend pointed that out to me. If I were to put JSON.stringify(data) then the post request worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to promisify the request module using a promise library like q, bluebird.

```
var request = bluebird.promisifyAll(require('request'));
```

else use request-promise which I hope returns the promise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It wasn't quite what I needed but I did find out a lot more about bluebird. It seems like a great choice to plug into mongoose. The mongoose exec function returns a promise but mongoose strongly suggests you plugin in your desired promise framework.

Comment: mongoose use mpromise by default which is been deprecated and gives you warning to inject your own promise library and bluebird has tons of feature and make your code look more clean